# How do I change the call from my left earphone to right?

Tags: settings

How do I change the call from my left earphone to my right one? I have trouble hearing in my left ear so I would prefer for the person whose on call for their voice to be coming from my right earphone, my phone is a Samsung s7

Comment: Are you sure both ears of your headset are correctly working? Because I would think that the sound would come from both sides at the same time. At least that is the case when I'm using a headset or something like that.

Answer (score 3):

Go to Settings --> Accessibility. Then tap Hearing. Towards the bottom, you will find an option for Mono Output, switch that ON. Then you can drop the earphone from one ear.

There is also a left-right sound balance. You can shift the slider to the ear you prefer.

Here is a guide to using the hearing accessibility settings on your phone:

https://www.androidcentral.com/how-use-hearing-accessibility-options-galaxy-s7